# Android "single top" launch mode and onNewIntent method

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent, android-manifest

I read in the Android documentation that by setting my Activity's launchMode property to singleTop OR by adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP` flag to my Intent, that calling `startActivity(intent)` would reuse a single Activity instance and give me the Intent in the `onNewIntent` callback.  I did both of these things, and `onNewIntent` never fires and `onCreate` fires every time.  The docs also say that `this.getIntent()` returns the intent that was first passed to the Activity when it was first created.  In `onCreate` I'm calling `getIntent` and I'm getting a new one every time (I'm creating the intent object in another activity and adding an extra to it...this extra should be the same every time if it was returning me the same intent object).  All this leads me to believe that my activity is not acting like a "single top", and I don't understand why.

To add some background in case I'm simply missing a required step, here's my Activity declaration in the manifest and the code I'm using to launch the activity.  The Activity itself doesn't do anything worth mentioning in regards to this:

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ArtistActivity"
        android:label="Artist"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
    </activity>
```

in my calling Activity:

```
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(EXTRA_KEY_ARTIST, id);
        i.setClass(this, ArtistActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        startActivity(i);
```

Comment: check this slideshow. It explains launchMode very good: http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Did you check if `onDestroy()` was called as well? That's probably why `onCreate()` gets invoked every time instead of `onNewIntent()`, which would only be called if the activity is already existing.

For example if you leave your activity via the BACK-button it gets destroyed by default. But if you go up higher on the activity stack into other activities and from there call your `ArtistActivity.class` again it will skip `onCreate()` and go directly to `onNewIntent()`, because the activity has already been created and since you defined it as `singleTop` Android won't create a new instance of it, but take the one that is already lying around.

What I do to see what's going on I implement dummy functions for all the different states of each activity so I always now what's going on:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy()");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Same for  `onRestart()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onDestroy()`

If the above (BACK-button) wasn't your problem, implementing these dummies will at least help you debugging it a bit better.

Comment: that is most likely what's going on.  I created something like a "landing page" activity as the entry point.  From the landing point, you select an artist and go to the ArtistActivity.  The user uses the back button to go back to the main activity and select again.  I was under the impression that the Activity would hang around after first use and that I'd save on performance by not re-instantiating it.  Should I worry about performance here, or is this pattern fine for simple activities?

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem as OP, but onDestroy never gets called in my case - I just end up with brand new instances of the activity :-s. Any other ideas ?

Comment: android:launchMode="singleTask" - in my case the ACtivity in question was getting started from outside its main task

Comment: @kellogs great tip. I'm working on a NFC-based app and every time a touched the phone with the tag, a new instance of my activity was started. The Jump-Back-Hierarchy was a mess. launchmode="singleTask" helps lot, the runtime enironment prevents instantiating multiple time  the same activity, which helped me a lot! Thx.

Comment: i see that ondestory() didn't be called. Only onStop() is called everytime. In fact, it is more likely enter directly to onResume(), neither onCreate(), nor onNewintent();

Comment: singleTask instead of singleTop fixed the issues I was having on Samsung devices only - emulator and other devices worked just fine. Samsung did not. singleTask fixed that issue.

Comment: singleTask limits you to only one instance of an activity in your task, which could conflict with how you want your application to behave in other use cases.  Using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT would likely be a better choice, as it reuses an existing activity by bringing it to the front of the stack.

Answer (score 39):

The accepted answer is not quite correct.  If onDestroy() was called previously, then yes, onCreate() would always be called.  However, **this statement is wrong**:
"If you go up higher on the activity stack into other activities and from there call your ArtistActivity.class again it will skip onCreate() and go directly to onNewIntent()"

The "singleTop" section of http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html explains plainly how it works (attention to bold text below; I've also proven this through my own debugging):

"For example, suppose a task's back stack consists of root activity A with activities B, C, and D on top (**the stack is A-B-C-D; D is on top**). An intent arrives for an activity of type D. If D has the default "standard"launch mode, a new instance of the class is launched and the stack becomes A-B-C-D-D. However, if D's launch mode is "singleTop", the existing instance of D receives the intent through onNewIntent(), because it's at the top of the stack—the stack remains A-B-C-D. However, **if an intent arrives for an activity of type B, then a new instance of B is added to the stack, even if its launch mode is "singleTop"."**

In other words, starting an activity through SINGLE_TOP will only reuse the existing activity if it is *already at the top of the stack*. It won't work if another activity in that same task is at the top (for example, the activity that is executing startActivity(SINGLE_TOP)); a new instance will be created instead.

**Here are two ways to fix this** so that you get the SINGLE_TOP behavior that you want -- the general purpose of which is to reuse an existing activity, instead of creating a new one...

**First way** (as described in the comment section of the accepted
   answer): You could add a launchMode of "singleTask" to your Activity.  This would force onNewIntent() because singleTask means there can only be ONE instance of a particular activity in a given task.  This is a somewhat hacky solution though because if your app needs multiple instances of that activity in a particular situation (like I do for my project), you're screwed.

**Second way (better):**
Instead of FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP, use FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT.  This will reuse the existing activity instance by moving it to the top of the stack (onNewIntent() will be called as expected).

The main purpose of FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is to prevent the creation of multiple instances of an Activity.  For instance, when that activity can be launched via an intent that comes from outside of your application's main task.  For internal switching between activities in my app, I've found that FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT is generally what I want instead.

Comment: Thank you. Indeed the accepted answer explanation is right for "singleTask" behaviour, but not for "singleTop" where up navigation can create several instances of one activity.

Comment: One thing.. In the second way, using FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT should still be combined with the the launchMode "singleTop" right?

Answer (score 3):

Set this flag to your intent:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP)
```