# Android application current activity bring to front issue

Tags: android, notifications, icons, statusbar, android-pendingintent

I have a basic question for which I don't think attaching any code-snippet may help. When we press home button while an app is in front we go to the home page and the app loses its focus.

Now, My application has to have notification icon in the status bar. And as in my application, there is a possibility of having 2-3 activity visible(one above another in dialogue view). In certain situation, I am not really sure as to how could I resume such state when I press notification icon in the status bar.

But, when I press home button and then press the application icon in the home screen I get everything as expected.

So, is there any way, by which I can do the same with notification bar icon.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are 2 ways of doing this:

1. [Notification to restore a task rather than a specific activity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity)
2. [Resume application and stack from notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5502427/resume-application-and-stack-from-notification)

Answer (score 0):

The notification bar icon is a `PendingIntent`, isn't it?
A PendingIntent can take an Intent to broadcast as soon as you click on the notification.
You can find an example at "[3. Define the notification's message and PendingIntent:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Basics)"