# Open a screen one time only

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

In MainActivity, I call SincActivity.
This screen has a "start" button, a TextView and a ProgressBar to show the status.

The button start an AsyncTask. This AsyncTask updates the components on the screen, and also in the notification area.

The notification area can be clicked. I passed into their creation which Activity it should open. I have spent SincActivity.

When the user is on the screen SincActivity and click the button, all components are updated as expected.

When I click on the notification area, android opens a new screen SincActivity, with initial values​​.

It's as if somewhere, android execute: "new SincActivity";
What I need is to be shown always the same screen.. the same instance. Almost like a singleton.

Is this possible?

**UPDATE**

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk
   android:minSdkVersion="11"
   android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
   android:allowBackup="true"
   android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
   android:label="@string/app_name"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
       android:name="br.com.rokko.gabinetemobile.MainActivity"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
       android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
       android:name="br.com.rokko.gabinetemobile.ModeloActivity"
       android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
       android:label="@string/title_activity_modelo"
       android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" >
    </activity>
    <activity
       android:name="br.com.rokko.gabinetemobile.SincActivity"
       android:label="@string/sincronizacao" ><!-- android:launchMode="singleInstance" don't work -->
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: post your manifest please

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:launchMode="singleInstance"` to the `<activity>` tag for this Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but actually is `android:launchMode="singleTask"`

Comment: Sorry. I must have made ​​a mistake in the test. In fact, both had no effect

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the notification to bring your task to the foreground, without creating any new instances of activities, you need to use a "launch Intent" in your notification. Something like this:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    // Set the action and category so it appears that the app is being launched
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

use `pendingIntent` when you create your notification.

For more information, see [Android application current activity bring to front issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11470520/android-application-current-activity-bring-to-front-issue)

Comment: Thanks, but I could not make it work. This is right? 
http://pastebin.com/nF5mcyPd

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code. I've edited my answer. You want to use `MainActivity` in the notification Intent, not `SincActivity`. The reason is that you want to simulate "relaunching" your application.