# How to switch to an existing activity, rather than start a new one

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a location service running and I want to alert the user if my main activity hasn't been active for several minutes, so from the service I am showing a notification with the code below (based on the example [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation)), using a flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` instead of `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`.
But it always starts a new copy of the activity, rather than carrying on where the existing one left off.

```
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class);
    resultIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
    resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        // Create the TaskStackBuilder and add the intent, which inflates the back stack
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ctx);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(resultIntent);
        // Get the PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
        stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(ctx);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID , builder.build());
```

Just to clarify, all I want to happen when the notification is clicked, is the same as what would happen if the standard task-switch control is used to navigate back to my activity when a different app is in use.

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-to-save-an-activity-state-using-save-instance-state) sounds the same as my situation, but all the answers explain in length about saving and restoring states. Why is this necessary, when I can switch between apps in the normal way without saving states?
I guess I'm misunderstanding something pretty basic here.

[Edit]

As mentioned in a  comment below, I have now [found an answer for Android 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity). But my Android 10 device still restarts the app rather than just switching to it.
In logcat I see the following at the time of the attempted switch:

```
2021-01-22 22:48:57.585 26173-26173/? I/n.wandrerhelpe: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2021-01-22 22:48:57.619 26173-26173/? E/n.wandrerhelpe: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
```

then there is a 2-second gap before the log shows the app starting from the beginning.

[Later edit]
After comments and more tests, my intent for the notification looks like this:

```
 Intent resultIntent = new Intent(ctx, NotificationActivity.class);
 PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0, resultIntent, 0);
```

with the simple NotificationActivity as suggested by @David Wasser:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Now finish, which will drop the user in to the activity that was at the top
    //  of the task stack
    finish();
}
```

All working well in Android 8 but not 10

Comment: I found this for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11470867/14759470 ... But, this answer here says that you shouldn't use "FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT" and that it doesn't do anything if you use it anyway. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19362852/14759470

Comment: Thanks. Following links I found that [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity ) works in Android 8, but not in Android 10, which still starts a new activity. So many difference new ways of working with Q! I'll keep experimenting.

Comment: You just want a Notification that brings your app to the foreground in whatever state it is in?

Comment: Also, using `TaskStackBuilder` is usually a disaster :-( `TaskStackBuilder` automatically clears the task and restarts it.

Comment: Yes, David, just to bring the app to the foreground as quickly as possible, __without restarting__, either from another app or when the screen has gone to sleep. I have removed ```TaskStackBuilder``` but still have the problem with Android 10