# Android notification intent uses old context

Tags: android, android-intent, android-asynctask, notifications

i'm writing a little image uploader app which uses the AsyncTask to upload and notification to let the user know if the upload is completed.

After the upload is finished i want to update the UI using the "onPostExecute"-Method from my AsyncTask-Thread. If you click on the notification it should navigate the user to the main activity where you can see all uploaded pictures(also the newest one).

*For that purpose i'm creating the notification in the "onPreExecute"-Method with the intent to come back:*

```
 @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle("ImageUpload")
        .setContentText("Uploading in progress")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, true);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
        PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(
                    0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
                );
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
        mNotifyManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

    }
```

The used context is passed when i'm creating the AsyncTask Object:

> new ImageUploader(getApplicationContext()).execute((getRealPathFromURI()));

After the upload is finished i'm changing the text of the notification and update the UI (in the moment only one TextView to test it):

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {           
        if(result == null) {
            setNotificationFinshedText("A error occured during the Upload");
        } else {
            setNotificationFinshedText("Upload complete!");
            txt.setText(result);
        }
    }
```

That works fine, after the "onPostExecute"-Method is finished i have the updated text in my activity and my "Upload complete!"-Notification in the bar.

**Now my problem begins:** If i click now, my notification opens the application but with the old context text / UI. That means my updated UI text disappears and is replaced with the old one.

For example:

1. Start App, text is: "placeholder text".
2. Start Upload, after its fnished the text is: "url: www.website.de/img.png".
3. Click Notification: Opens Activity, text is again: "placeholder text".

**My idea:** It's because the returning intent is using my "old" activity context which is set before i change the UI. But i don't know how to solve this problem. Is it possible to set the resultIntent and TaskStackBuilder in the "onPostExecute"-Method after updating the UI ?

Comment: I assume that a new instance of `MainActivity` is being created when you select the notification. You can verify this by adding some logging in `onCreate()` of `MainActivity`. If all you want to do is to bring the existing application to the foreground, you can look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11470867/769265). I also don't know why you are using `TaskStackBuilder` since you aren't building a back stack (with multiple activities). You can just get use `PendingIntent.getActivity()` for this purpose.

Comment: i will take a look at your answer, i'm new to notifications so i used the google developers tutorial which used the TaskStackBuilder.