# How to manage Pending Intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

I have a problem with **Pending Intent** in my app.

I have an activity, a notification with pending intent to launch that activity.

When my app is **NOT displayed** ( not foreground), I scroll the notification bar down and launch my app from my notification. It works fine.

But when **my app is foreground**, I want the **activity is not launched again** if user press on my notification because It has been displayed already.

**I don't want my pending intent launch the activity** in this case. How can I do or please give me some key word for searching?

Comment: you could cancel the notification whenever your application is visible.

Comment: How can I do that. My notification is in a Service?

Comment: In your launching `Activity` try `android:launchMode` with `singleInstance`

Comment: Oh, I use singleTask and It works fine, singleintance just solves my problem but make more bad things. thank you so much for suggesting.

Comment: I think that not displaying the notification when the user is in the app may be the best option. It depends on your usecase of course. I display a notification when my music app is playing a track, but as soon as the user enters the app, I use notification.cancel to hide it (and I recreate it in onPause)

Comment: If you have solved your problem by creating your activity singleInstance/singleTask then please avoid using it, better is to clear the notification programmatically.

Comment: I'm using Foreground Service with Pending Intent.

Comment: Hello, I have tried a method that CommonWare tell me and It worked. Just add flag FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP to intent that PendingIntent uses.

Comment: Please see my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity