# How to bring my app in foreground without use of ActivityManager?

Tags: android, android-broadcast, start-activity, activity-manager

**EDIT**

You can find the answer to this question in the comments !

**POST**

In my app, I have timers to remind the user of some task he's supposed to do. When time is up, a notification is sent. When the user clicks on this notification, I would like my **app to be put in foreground** if it's not already the case. I insist on the 
'app' because I have found many posts that show how to put an `Activity` in foreground, which is not the case here.

Here is the code of the Broadcastreceiver that is called when I would like to send the notification and bring my app to foreground:

```
public class TimerBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    int ID = 333;
    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.clock_alarm2);
    builder.setContentTitle("Time is up");
    builder.setContentText("SLIMS");
    builder.setOnlyAlertOnce(false);
    Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    builder.setSound(uri);
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 0, 200, 3000 });
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    // get the info from the currently running task
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = activityManager.getRunningTasks(100);

    for (int i = 0; i < taskInfo.size(); i++) {
        String componentName = taskInfo.get(i).topActivity.getClassName();
        if (componentName.contains("com.genohm.android")) {
            Intent intentActivity = new Intent();
            intentActivity.setComponent(taskInfo.get(i).topActivity);
            intentActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intentActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        }
    }

    final Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_INSISTENT;
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    NotificationManager mNM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNM.notify(ID, notification);
}
}
```

This code **works perfectly**. The problem is that I'm using the method [getRunningTasks()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks%28int%29) whose use seems to be **strongly discouraged** by Google.

> Such uses are not supported, and will likely break in the future.

But actually it's the only way I found so far. 
Does anyone know if some workaround exists for this kind of practice ?

Comment: Why 'app' and not Activity? You want to see more details about the notification in the Activity. It's will be confusing for the user to go back to last Activity of that app, which will be doing something completely diffenent (For example in the settings menu of your app...)

Comment: Well I have different Activities. Imagine the user put some timer. He uses the app and navigates through some Activities. At some point he decides to use an other application. When time is up, the user is notified. He can simply press on the Notification and continue to use the app as he left it. I don't want any precise Activity to be launched.

Comment: Look at my answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575730/notification-to-restore-a-task-rather-than-a-specific-activity) that shows how to do what you want

Comment: Yes it worked perfectly. I recommend [the post from David](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7286683/1685143), it helped me resolving my issue.