# How to make the up-button go back to a parent activity on the back stack?

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

I'd like to implement the following behavior for the up-button:

- If an instance of the parent activity is on the back stack, return to the top-most instance of that parent activity.
- If there is no instance of the parent activity on the back stack, create a new instance.

Actually, when I first read about the difference between up and back, this behaviors was what I expected as default. However, I have seen now, that `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);` always creates a new instance of the parent activity, ignoring the fact, that there is one readily available on the back stack.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify launch mode for your activity in Manifest  android:launchMode="singleInstance" or android:launchMode="singleTop" ,look at this question for more info [Android launchmode="singleTask" does not work as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169055/android-launchmode-singletask-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 0):

> If an instance of the parent activity is on the back stack, return to the top-most instance of that parent activity.

If this is meant to clear the back stack down to this top-most instance, I recently solved this issue customizing the up-navigation using the activity's `onOptionsItemSelected()` and adding the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP`-flag ([link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp)) to the `Intent` - while only switching the launch mode did not end up in the back stack I was expecting:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
    Intent parentActivityIntent = NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this);
    parentActivityIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
}
```

Also have a look at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp.